# Does connect() block for TCP socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Hi I am reading TLPI (The Linux Programming Interface), I have a question about connect().

As I understand, connect() will immediately return if the pending connection numbers of listen() doesn't reach "backlog".
And it will blocks otherwise. (according to figure 56-2)

But for TCP socket, it will always block until accept() on server side is called (according to figure 61-5).

Am I correct?
Because I saw that in the example code (p.1265), it calls listen() to listen to a specific port and then calls connect() to that port BEFORE calling accept().

So connect() blocks forever in this case, doesn't it?

Thanks!!

Comment: If that's what figure 56-2 really shows, it's wrong.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's hardly any "immediately" regarding networking, stuff can be lost on the way, and an operation that should be performed immediately in theory might not do so in practice, and in any case there's the end to end transmission time.

However

- connect() on a TCP socket is a blocking operation unless the socket descriptor is put into non-blocking mode.
- The OS takes care of the TCP handshake, when the handshake is finished, connect() returns. (that is, 
  connect() does not block until the other end calls accept())
- A successful TCP handshake will be queued to the server application, and can be accept()'ed any time later.

Comment: Just wanted to add that `connect` just wait for the handshake and not for the server to call `accept`, is because of two reasons: The first is that from the clients side he is connected after the handshake; The second is because there can pass an arbitrary time between the handshake, and before the servers calls `accept` which can indeed be forever.

Comment: Even without the rest of the answer, "there's hardly any 'immediately`" alone warrants a +1. This is so true for a lot of operations, even in nonblocking mode. Immediately can be a _surprisingly_ long time sometimes, even for things where you'd really not expect it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg @nos If `connect()` returns before the server calls `accept()`, what happens if the client then tries to `send()` before the server has called `accept()`?

Comment: @Andrew The data is buffered by the receiving systems network stack, up until the buffer is full in which case the receiving network stack will reply with an empty window which causes the sending side to return from the `send` call with an error.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Hmm so why do we say `connect()` blocks? If the server has called `listen()` then it returns immediately (after the handshake) and if the server hasn't called `listen()` then it returns with an error.

Comment: @Andrew  As mentioned, there's no "immediately". It could take many (hundreds) of miliseconds to complete the hand shake over a network. There's literally millions of things you could do in that time insted of waiting (blocking) for the handshake to complete.

Comment: @nos Fair enough, thanks. I didn't realise `connect()` returned without the server application doing anything.

Answer (score 6):

connect() blocks until finishing TCP 3-way handshake. Handshake on listening side is handled by TCP/IP stack in kernel and finished without notifying user process. Only after handshake is completed (and initiator can return from connect() call already), accept() in user process can pick up new socket and return. No waiting accept() needed for completing handshake.

The reason is simple: if you have single threaded process listening for connections and require waiting accept() for establishing connections, you can't respond to TCP SYN's while processing another request. TCP stack on initating side will retransmit, but on moderately loaded server chances are high this retransmitted packet still will arrive while no accept() pending and will be dropped again, resulting in ugly delays and connection timeouts.

Answer (score 3):

[`connect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) is a blocking call by default, but you can make it non blocking by passing to [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) the `SOCK_NONBLOCK` flag.

Comment: Or more commonly, using the "traditional" BSD socket function of fcntl with O_NONBLOCK. SOCK_NONBLOCK is Linux-specific.