# Blocking sockets to non-blocking sockets

Tags: c++, ipc

Can anyone help me, how to change the below code to non-blocking

```
struct sockaddr_un server_address;
int server_len, err;
int ret = 1;

int ipc_sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (ipc_sockfd < 0) {
    printf("%s\n","SHM_IPC: socket creation failed");
    return 0;
}
server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(server_address.sun_path, SHM_IPC_SOCKET_NAME);
server_len = sizeof(server_address);

err = connect(ipc_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address,
              server_len);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("%s %d\n", "IPC socket server not ready for"
                            ". Try after few moments, Errno:", errno);
    close(ipc_sockfd);
    return 0;
}

err = write(ipc_sockfd, (void *)msg, sizeof(shm_ipc_msg));
if (err <=0) {
    printf("%s %d\n", "SHM_IPC: socket write failed:",errno);
    ret = 0;
}
close(ipc_sockfd);
return ret;
```

This is my client side socket, i need my client side write() and connect() to be non-blocking (I dont care about server side), do I need to change the server socket also to non-blocking to take effect?

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

This thread might help you: [Does connect() block for TCP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258107/does-connect-block-for-tcp-socket)

You can make your connect non-blocking but for what reason? if the client is not connected to the server you cannot expect socket.write to work. You need to wait until the connection it's done. The write operation though it is not a blocking operation. If the connection is established the write function should return immediately after sending your data.